# Алгоритмическая задача на Rate Limiter

Tags: java, алгоритм

Имеется задача, где есть **отсортированный список UNIX дат** (unix timestamp с точностью до миллисекунд - unsigned 64 bit integer). Вместе с датами так же присутствует и специальный пользовательский токен. Например:

```
1676217286199 RjY2NjM5NzA2OWJjuE7c 
1676217287012 RjY2NjM5NzA2OWJjuE7c 
1676217287612 RjY2NjM5NzA2OWJjuE7c
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы описать функцию accept. Она должна вернуть true если количество запросов в диапазоне секунды не привысило N для пользователя (определяется по токену). Другими словами -  не более N раз в секунду.

Вот пример тестовых данных

```
1679982033000 441079aa62dc3cd57df3 
1679982033998 441079aa62dc3cd57df3 
1679982033999 441079aa62dc3cd57df3 
1679982034000 441079aa62dc3cd57df3
```

Применяю функцию accept, на выходе должно остаться

```
1679982033000 441079aa62dc3cd57df3 
1679982033998 441079aa62dc3cd57df3 
1679982034000 441079aa62dc3cd57df3
```

Эту задачу я решал следующим алгоритмом:

1. Если в мапе нет по токену никакого времени, то кладу в мапу пару - текущее время и количество запрашиваемых запросов
2. если мы укладываемся в период 1 секунды и у нас еще не превышен лимит N, то мы пропускаем запрос (увеличиваем счетчик)
3. если мы находимся в другом "окне", то мы должны сбросить счётчик до 1 и обновляем время, чтобы считать окно с текущим интервалом (в задаче время отсортировано)
4. в обратном случае мы не пускаем запрос

   ```
   Map<String, Long[]> lastRequestTimes = new HashMap<>();
    boolean accept(String token, long timestamp) {
        lastRequestTimes.putIfAbsent(token, new Long[]{timestamp, 1L});
        long lastRequestTime = lastRequestTimes.get(token)[0]; // Получаем последнее время запроса для текущего токена
        if (timestamp / 1000L - lastRequestTime / 1000 == 0 && lastRequestTimes.get(token)[1] <= n) {
            ++lastRequestTimes.get(token)[1];
            return true;
        } else if (timestamp / 1000L - lastRequestTime / 1000 != 0) {
            lastRequestTimes.get(token)[1] = 1L;
            lastRequestTimes.get(token)[0] = timestamp;
           return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
   ```

Данный код где-то содержит логическую ошибку. У меня есть предположение, что неверно обрабатывается edge-кейсы. Вероятно нужно класть в пустую мапу со счётчиком 0, дальше увеличивать счётчик через if-else и дальше проверять, не вышли ли мы за пределы N. Помогите найти логическую ошибку в алгоритме.

Comment: Как-то у Вас странно с тестовыми данными... Почему отбрасывается запись из середины предложенного списка?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, "в диапазоне секунды" не означает промежутки по границам целых секунд, а любые отрезки длиной в секунду.

Держите в мапе пары  `токен:очередь с временами` (Queue, если у вас в Java есть готовая, да и любой список подойдёт)

По приходу данных берете токен и время, и удаляете из начала соответствующей токену очереди времена, отстоящие более чем на 1000 мс.

Добавляете время в конец очереди

Если после этого длина очереди меньше или равна `N`, возвращаете `true`

Comment: Я попробовал вашу идею https://pastecode.io/s/1if4wxvc
К сожалению она не работает, либо я допустил ошибку в коде. Из представленных тестовых данных у меня почему-то аксептнулось первые 3 ввода, хотя должно быть иначе...

Comment: Если я правильно понял задачу, то текущее время (новый таймстамп)  надо добавлять всегда, независимо от длины очереди.

Comment: @Aleksandr T Похоже на то, что нужно, но учтите, что Юрий Козлов подсказывает. У меня написана последовательность - сначала добавили, потом проверяем длину

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов не уверен что нужно добавлять в ведро запрос, если оно уже переполнено…

Comment: @AleksandrT, да нужно. То что ведро переполнено сейчас не означает что вы можете игнорировать данные важные для следующей секунды.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если добавлять в очередь элемент в начале, то тогда можно таки нарваться на неправильное выполнение функции. Вы говорите "вы можете игнорировать данные важные для следующей секунды". Не совсем понятно, как это? Если в текущем окне t_i - 1 sec у нас уже есть N элементов в очереди, тогда нельзя пропускать текущий запрос. Как только будет t_j, которое покроет окно t_j - 1 sec, где количество входящих запросов было <= N, тогда можно добавлять: https://pastecode.io/s/1vgg45ni

Comment: @AleksandrT Вопрос гласит "количество запросов", а не "количество принятых запросов". В этом случае в последовательности 3998 3999 4000 последний запрос является третьим за 2 мс и не должен быть принят

Comment: @AleksandrT Перечитал внимательно Ваш вопрос. Вывод: либо Вы неверно сформулировали задачу, либо неверно ее понимаете. Уточните: для того, чтобы функция ```accept``` вернула ```true``` проверяется количество поступивших от пользователя запросов за единицу времени или количество удовлетворенных запросов?